# Non norma distribution

Tags: distributions, anova, nonparametric

I have a non-normal distribution (Kilograms ~ Years), so I can't use ANOVA test to reject the null hypothesis (that the tree means are equal).
There is a tendency of weight to be 100kg.
Is there a way to test if there are differences between the groups?

[image]

Comment: In what sense do plots of years vs. kilograms represent "distributions"??  Is it possible that the vertical axis actually is *probability density* and that you are showing *three* distributions, not one?

Comment: @whuber yes, it is probability density and it is showing three distributions to be compare. 'Years' is the title of the box, even though it is looking like a vertical axis label

Comment: Thank you.  How many observations do you have in each group?  Do you want to compare group means or other kinds of differences as well?

Comment: @whuber after undersampling, I have 155 observations for each group. I want to compare means, I want to say that there are differences  between the mean of groups

Comment: "Undersampling" raises some flags because it suggests (at a minimum) that you have lost potentially useful information in doing so: what are you undersampling and why?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your attention :)
The number os observations were differents

30 ->  1718,  40 ->   270, 20 ->  165

Comment: There is no need to sample: use all your data.

Comment: @whuber but even using all data, the distribution are not gaussian distributions. The question is: I have to choose the correct test or transform my data?

Comment: The distributions themselves do not matter: all you need is for the *sampling distribution of the test statistic* to be close to what is expected.  When the underlying distributions are compact, not terribly skewed, and group sizes are sufficiently large, the ANOVA variance ratios will be accurately modeled by the $F$ ratio distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two approaches to dealing with non-normal data: either transform the data or use a non-parametric test.

### Data Transformations

You can try to transform your means all kinds of ways. If you search online people will recommend all kinds of transformations for different situations.

I recently had some success using the rank transformation method in [Conover and Iman (1981)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.1981.10479327). Take your data from all groups and place them in a single pool. Sort from smallest to largest and assign ranks such that 1 is the smallest number. In cases of ties (for example, duplicate values) assign the average rank for all tying-values.

Then use the normal parametric method on these ranked data.

### Nonparametric Options

If you can't or don't want to transform your data consider a non-parametric option. In your use case you might consider the [Kruskal-Wallis test](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/kruskal-wallis-h-test-using-spss-statistics.php), which is kind of a text-book answer for a non-parametric replacement for ANOVA. There are certainly other (and in some cases, better) tools too.

### ...or maybe nothing at all

You'd like to avoid these complicated options if you could, right? So just use the bog-standard ANOVA test. It's probably just fine even with non-normally distributed data (for example, [Bianca et al. 2017](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29048317)). Pay more attention to the homogeneity of variances and not how the data is distributed.